# Locating lua table.find() methods in documentation

Tags: lua

I've attempted to locate this method in the documentation but haven't been successful. Can anyone shed light on why this might be the case? The documentation link is https://www.lua.org/docs.html.

Interestingly, I stumbled upon this information in a game engine, yet it doesn't appear in the general Lua documentation. Is it perhaps a special feature exclusive to the game engine? I'm having difficulty understanding the reason behind this. If anyone could provide an explanation, I'd appreciate it. The game engine documentation link is https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/libraries/table#find.

Thank you.

Comment: Roblox uses its own version of Lua (called [Luau](https://luau-lang.org/)). Luau is not Lua. Lua does not have a `table.find`, but Luau does.